# What is the "lifespan" of a postgres CTE expression? e.g. WITH... AS

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression

I have a CTE I am using to pull some data from two tables then stick in an intermediate table called `cte_list`, something like

```
  with cte_list as (
        select pl.col_val from prune_list pl join employees.employee emp on pl.col_val::uuid = emp.id
        where pl.col_nm = 'employee_ref_id' limit 100
        )
```

***Then***, I am doing an insert to move records from the `cte_list` to another archive table (if they don't exist) called `employee_arch_test`

```
 insert into employees.employee_arch_test (
      select * from employees.employee where id in (select col_val::uuid from cte_list)
      and not exists (select 1 from employees.employee_arch_test where employees.employee_arch_test.id=employees.employee.id)
      );
```

This seems to work fine. The problem is when I add another statement after, to do some **deletions** from the main `employee` table using this aforementioned `cte_list` - the cte_list apparently no longer exists?

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "cte_list" does not exist
```

the actual delete query:

```
delete from employees.employee where id in (select col_val::uuid from cte_list);
```

***Can the `cte_list` CTE table only be used once or something?*** I'm running these statements in a LOOP and I need to run the exact same calls for about 2 or 3 other tables but hit a sticking point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE only exists for the duration of the statement of which it's a part. I gather you have an INSERT statement with the CTE preceding it:

```
with cte_list
  as (select pl.col_val
        from prune_list pl
        join employees.employee emp
          on pl.col_val::uuid = emp.id
        where pl.col_nm = 'employee_ref_id'
        limit 100
        )
 insert into employees.employee_arch_test
   (select *
      from employees.employee
      where id in (select col_val::uuid from cte_list)
            and not exists (select 1
                              from employees.employee_arch_test
                              where employees.employee_arch_test.id = employees.employee.id)
   );
```

The CTE is **part of** the INSERT statement - it is not a separate statement by itself. It only exists for the duration of the INSERT statement.

If you need something which lasts longer your options are:

1. Add the same CTE to each of your following statements. Note that because data may be changing in your database each invocation of the CTE may return different data.
2. Create a view which performs the same operations as the CTE, then use the view in place of the CTE. Note that because data may be changing in your database each invocation of the view may return different data.
3. Create a temporary table to hold the data from your CTE query, then use the temporary table in place of the CTE. This has the advantage of providing a consistent set of data to all operations.

Comment: Jarvis thank you I think this answers it perfectly